# how to set up service account private key for postman to access google api?

Tags: postman, service-accounts

To access google API, we can use oauth2 clientid, which it is called 3 legged approach. We can also use service account, which it is called 2 legged approach.

I want to connect to Google API through service account private key. (2 legged approach) by using postman

http://engineering-blog.alphasights.com/using-service-accounts-to-act-on-behalf-of-your-google-apps-users/

So my questions would be how to set up service account private key for postman to access google api.